# Does this entangled PDE capture the derivative?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

In a game-theory textbook, I encountered the following. Suppose we have player $1$ and and $2$ optimizing by playing strategies $x_1$ and $x_2$ $\in \mathbb{R}$. The first order conditions for player $1$ and $2$ are given respectively by:
$$f(x_1,x_2,a,b)=1$$
$$g(x_1,x_2,a,b)=1$$

What is $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial b}$? Naively, we may apply the implicit function theorem:

$$\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial b}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial a}}{\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_1}}$$

But given that $a$ is also a function of the first order condition for the second player, we must take into account the effect of $a$ **through its effect on $x_2$**. Hence, the PDE is given by

$$\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial a}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial a}*\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_2}}{\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1}*\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_2}}$$

Where $x_2$ satisfies player $2$'s FOC. In the numerator, the term $\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial a}*\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_2}$ captures the effect of $a$ **through** $x_2$ on $f(..)$, and the $\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1}*\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_2}$ the effect of $x_1$ **through** $x_2$ on $f(..)$. Is this a correct application of the inverse function theorem that produces a good approximation of $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial b}$?

---

One factor that makes me hesitant about this PDE is in the numerator, the term $\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial a}*\frac{\partial f(..)}{\partial x_2}$ captures the effect of $a$ on $x_2$. However, this is exactly what we're trying to define all along, albeit for $x_1$. At any rate, this part will not completely characterize the effect of $a$ on $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you differentiate both equations in $a$, you get
$$
f_a+x^1_af_1+x^2_af_2=0,\\
g_a+x^1_ag_1+x^2_ag_2=0,
$$
where I'm denoting $x^j_a=\partial x^j/\partial a$ and $f_j=\partial f/\partial x^j$.  If we solve this system for $x^1_a$, we get
$$
x^1_a=\frac{f_2g_a-g_2f_a}{g_2f_1-g_1f_2}.
$$
Using Jacobians, you can express this as
$$
\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial a}=-\frac{\partial(f,g)/\partial(a,x^2)}{\partial (f,g)/\partial(x^1,x^2)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you provide some context? Is yours a better approach? Does the approach I describe succeed in your opinion?

Comment: If you are taking $x_1,x_2$ to be functions of $(a,b)$, then this is the approach to use.  Compare with the one-dimensional situation, $f(a,x)=1$.  If you want $dx/da$, you can implicitly differentiate in $a$ and solve for $dx/da$.

Comment: These functions are implicitly defined by their first order condition, and cannot be expressed in closed form. Do you take this into account? Also, can you provide me some reference for this approach?

Comment: Yes, implicit definitions are no problem.  Here is the reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem